# Material-ul Style not working properly ,getting Warning: Prop `className` did not match. Server

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

Style not working properly using Material-ui with Next js.

Getting warning:

> "Warning: Prop `className` did not match. Server:"

I have used below  Nextjs With Material-ui [example](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/next/examples/nextjs-next).

Environment:

```
Ubuntu : 18.10
Material-ui: 3.9.3
NextJs : 8.0.4
```

I have created custom server file (server.js) for production (PM2 server.js) Its working fine on the local machine using `npm run dev` command but on the live server, I think there is some issue with custom `server.js` file.

Server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const next = require("next");

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express();

  server.get("*", (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res);
  });

  server.listen(port, err => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
});
```

Packege.json file

```
{
  "name": "nextjs-next",
  "version": "4.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "next",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.2",
    "@material-ui/styles": "next",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.3.1",
    "clsx": "latest",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "graphql": "^14.2.0",
    "isomorphic-unfetch": "^3.0.0",
    "joi-browser": "^13.4.0",
    "jss": "next",
    "next": "latest",
    "prop-types": "latest",
    "react": "latest",
    "react-apollo": "^2.5.3",
    "react-dom": "latest"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "prod_start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js"
  }
}
```

Anyone please suggest possible solutions to fix this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it should be `pm2 start server.js`, not pm2 server.js. If the app acts weird, put it in your scripts tag `"prod_server": "NODE_ENV=production pm2 start server.js"`. Hope this helps